# need hel with shell commands to python

Tags: python-3.x, openssl

I have this shell script that creates openssl signature with payload, date etc. I am trying to convert that into a python script. I could not get pass this section of bash script code. Can you please help in Python 3.11.3.

```
body='{"tenantId":"ocid1.tenancy.oc1.abcd","granularity":"MONTHLY","timeUsageStarted":"2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","timeUsageEnded":"2023-11-30T00:00:00.000Z","filter":null,"compartmentDepth":6,"queryType":"COST","groupBy":["compartmentName","compartmentDepth"]}'

content_sha256="$(openssl dgst -binary -sha256 < $body | openssl enc -e -base64)";
content_sha256_header="x-content-sha256: $content_sha256"
content_length="$(wc -c < $body | xargs)";
content_length_header="content-length: $content_length"
headers="(request-target) date host"
# add on the extra fields required for a POST/PUT
headers=$headers" x-content-sha256 content-type content-length"
content_type_header="content-type: application/json";


echo "$content_sha256"
echo "$content_sha256_header"
echo "$content_length"
echo "$content_length_header"
```

result of the above bash script

```
GKCwMjiRQ44nRsViLa1NwEX3rQelIEaCQG5L7VFl3Jc=
x-content-sha256: GKCwMjiRQ44nRsViLa1NwEX3rQelIEaCQG5L7VFl3Jc=
384
content-length: 384
```

I am not sure how to covert these openssl commands in script to python so asking for help

so far i tried

```
content_sha256=subprocess.run(
    ["openssl", "dgst", "-binary", "-sha256"],
    input=body,
    check=True
).stdout

print(content_sha256)
```

I get this below error

```
   content_sha256=subprocess.run(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 550, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1192, in communicate
    self._stdin_write(input)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _stdin_write
    self.stdin.write(input)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I also tried

```
cmd="openssl dgst -binary -sha256 < "+body+" | openssl enc -e -base64"
content_sha256=call(cmd, shell=True)
print(content_sha256)
```

That resulted in 0 as the output.